# Asterisk REGEX returning 0

Tags: asterisk

I work with asterisk-11.2.1 I want to  use REGEX and wrote this code

```
${REGEX("^foo$","foo")}
```

and return 0. Please help me , why 0?

Comment: don't forget to `core show function REGEX` on the asterisk CLI, it'll give you the proper syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried with `${REGEX("^foo$" foo)}`? Is it work?